# Website's search function with Python requests

Tags: python, search, python-requests

Cannot successfully implement website's search function using python requests. Performing search at the website results with https://bidbaits.ru/search/#used=1&new=1&original=1&replica=1&auctions=1&fixedPrice=1&discount=0&trustedSeller=0&lockLocation=0&q=cyarl&c=0&orderBy=2, but performing it with requests return nothing:

```
r = requests.get('https://bidbaits.ru/search/#used=1&new=1&original=1&replica=1&auctions=1&fixedPrice=1&discount=0&trustedSeller=0&lockLocation=0&q=cyarl&c=0&orderBy=2')
print(r.text)
```

Also, how is it possible to send query as a parameter?

Comment: looks like there is some problem with both the urls, can you please verify and update the  links.

Comment: There might be something wrong with headers, are you including any headers?\

Comment: No, I include no headers. The URL is working fine - I just checked. Actually it showing some results as a search

Comment: some servers may need some headers for different reasons - they may need header `user-agent` to recognize device and screen size and send different HTML for screen size. It may also need some headers to recognize bots/scripts/spamers/hackers and block them.

Comment: this page uses `JavaScript` to display results but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript  and you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. Eventually you can check in `DevTools` in `Firefox/Chrome` if `JavaScript` reads data from other URL (usually as JSON data) and then you can use this URL with `requests` to get results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` to display elements on page but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`.

But using `DevTools` in `Chrome/Firefox` you can see `JavaScript` (`AJAX`/`XHR`) reads data from other url

https://bidbaits.ru/searchresults/?page=1&seo=SEARCH&orderBy=2&used=1&new=1&original=1&replica=1&auctions=1&fixedPrice=1&discount=0&trustedSeller=0&lockLocation=0&q=cyarl&c=0

which works with `requests` if you use header `Referer`.
(I checked it manually running code with different headers)

I use module `json` only to display it with indentations. You can work directly with dictionary `data`.

```
import requests

#s = requests.Session()

headers = {
    #'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
    #'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    #'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',  # AJAX
    'Referer': 'https://bidbaits.ru/',
}

url = 'https://bidbaits.ru/searchresults/?page=1&seo=SEARCH&orderBy=2&used=1&new=1&original=1&replica=1&auctions=1&fixedPrice=1&discount=0&trustedSeller=0&lockLocation=0&q=cyarl&c=0'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)    

data = r.json() 

#print(data)

import json

print(json.dump(data, indent=2))
```

Result:

```
{
  "totalCount": "4",
  "totalCountMsg": "\u041d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d\u043e <span class=\"b-bsr_count\">4</span> \u0432\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0430\u043d\u0442\u0430",
  "items": [
    {
      "itemId": "544665",
      "name": "Jackson Cyarl Blade 48F 4g Sinking Ama Gaeru Rain Frog",
      "price": "700",
      "isSpecialOffer": false,
      "isRecommendedItem": false,
      "priceSpecial": 0,
      "url": "/bids/544665/",
      "imageUrl": "//c.bidbaits.ru/items/544665/thumb/1580816722-0419.JPG",
      "userName": "Survivor-Demon",
      "userRating": "658",
      "userUrl": "/users/survivor-demon/",
      "typeId": "3",
      "bets": "0 \u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043e\u043a",
      "isTrusted": true,
      "timeLeft": 235373
    },
    {
      "itemId": "735811",
      "name": "Jackson Cyarl 20mm 1,8g sinking",
      "price": "450",
      "isSpecialOffer": false,
      "isRecommendedItem": false,
      "priceSpecial": 0,
      "url": "/bids/735811/",
      "imageUrl": "//c.bidbaits.ru/items/735811/thumb/1600933789-5099.jpg",
      "userName": "Dmitr79",
      "userRating": "22",
      "userUrl": "/users/dmitr79/",
      "typeId": "3",
      "bets": "0 \u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043e\u043a",
      "isTrusted": false,
      "timeLeft": 572273
    },
    {
      "itemId": "840409",
      "name": "Jackson Cyarl 25S (1,8 \u0433.) OT",
      "price": "700",
      "isSpecialOffer": false,
      "isRecommendedItem": false,
      "priceSpecial": 0,
      "url": "/bids/840409/",
      "imageUrl": "//c.bidbaits.ru/items/840409/thumb/1611249724-4935.JPG",
      "userName": "Ima2021",
      "userRating": "6",
      "userUrl": "/users/ima2021/",
      "typeId": "3",
      "bets": "0 \u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043e\u043a",
      "isTrusted": false,
      "timeLeft": 2050658
    },
    {
      "itemId": "840416",
      "name": "Jackson Cyarl 25S (1,8 \u0433.) PA",
      "price": "700",
      "isSpecialOffer": false,
      "isRecommendedItem": false,
      "priceSpecial": 0,
      "url": "/bids/840416/",
      "imageUrl": "//c.bidbaits.ru/items/840416/thumb/1611250255-9944.JPG",
      "userName": "Ima2021",
      "userRating": "6",
      "userUrl": "/users/ima2021/",
      "typeId": "3",
      "bets": "0 \u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043e\u043a",
      "isTrusted": false,
      "timeLeft": 2051635
    }
  ],
  "currentPage": 1,
  "hasNextPage": false,
  "isSEO": false,
  "pageTitle": "\u041f\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a: cyarl",
  "
```

---

Working directly with `data`

```
data = r.json() 

#print(data)
#import json
#print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))

for item in data['items']:
    print('name:', item['name'])
    print('price:', item['price'])    
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
name: Jackson Cyarl Blade 48F 4g Sinking Ama Gaeru Rain Frog
price: 700
---
name: Jackson Cyarl 20mm 1,8g sinking
price: 450
---
name: Jackson Cyarl 25S (1,8 г.) OT
price: 700
---
name: Jackson Cyarl 25S (1,8 г.) PA
price: 700
---
```